# How do I turn a redis string value that is a numpy array into a dataframe quickly?

Tags: r, performance, caching, redis

I currently have a python program which does some calculating of time series data, and sends datapts to a redis cache. Each data point is a numpy array which looks like this:

"[ 1.18103230e+07  7.89070000e+04 -1.88109969e-01 -2.17373938e-01\n  1.00433488e+01 -1.39566174e-03 -1.95357823e-03  8.36936470e-02\n -1.26680427e+00 -1.85034338e+00  2.00000000e+00]"

Then, I want R to call the cache and convert this string in a dataframe or list of some sort. Currently I have this:

```
    len <- as.numeric(as.character(redisLLen(list)))
    v <- redisLRange(list, 0, len)
    counter <- 1
    for (item in v) {
      item <- strsplit(gsub("(^\\[|\\]$)", "", v), ",")[[counter]]
      item <- strsplit(item, " +")
      df <- rbind(df, item)
      counter <- counter + 1
    }
```

This works fine and there is no issues, but the problem is the R code has to work in realtime and this is actually a very slow method. Are they any faster ways to turn this redis string value into an R dataframe? Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

In my python code I removed the square brackets, so that there would be less to remove in gsub() in R. Moreover, a good chunk of time was spent doing rbind(). So instead of adding to a dataframe, I made an initial one, and inserted elements. This is now the data point:

"1.18103230e+07  7.89070000e+04 -1.88109969e-01 -2.17373938e-01\n  1.00433488e+01 -1.39566174e-03 -1.95357823e-03  8.36936470e-02\n -1.26680427e+00 -1.85034338e+00  2.00000000e+00",

and this is the updated code I now use:

```
    len <- as.numeric(redisLLen(list))
    v <- redisLRange(list, 0, len-1)
    df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 8, nrow=len))
    counter <- 1
    for (item in v) {
      item <- unlist(strsplit(item, " +"))
      df[counter, 1:ncol(df)] <- item
      counter <- counter + 1
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a string, then we can use `read.table`

```
read.table(text = gsub("[][]", "", v1), header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
#        V1            V2           V3          V4
#1  1.181032e+07  7.890700e+04 -0.188109969 -0.21737394
#2  1.004335e+01 -1.395662e-03 -0.001953578  0.08369365
#3 -1.266804e+00 -1.850343e+00  2.000000000          NA
```

Or more faster `fread`

```
library(data.table)
fread(text = gsub("[][]", "", v1))
```

---

If we need as a single column, read with `scan` and convert to `data.frame`

```
v2 <- scan(text = gsub("[][\n]", "", v1), what = numeric(), quiet = TRUE)
data.frame(col1 = v2)
#           col1
#1   1.181032e+07
#2   7.890700e+04
#3  -1.881100e-01
#4  -2.173739e-01
#5   1.004335e+01
#6  -1.395662e-03
#7  -1.953578e-03
#8   8.369365e-02
#9  -1.266804e+00
#10 -1.850343e+00
#11  2.000000e+00
```

Or with `fread`

```
fread(text = gsub(' ', '\n', gsub("[][]|\n", "", v1)))
```

---

It is not clear how the object was created.  We could convert `python` objects to `R` using `reticulate`

```
library(reticulate)
np <- import("numpy", convert=FALSE)
np1 <- np$array(c(1.18103230e+07, 7.89070000e+04, -1.88109969e-01, -2.17373938e-01,1.00433488e+01, -1.39566174e-03, -1.95357823e-03, 8.36936470e-02,
     -1.26680427e+00, -1.85034338e+00, 2.00000000e+00))
data.frame(col1 = py_to_r(np1))
#          col1
#1   1.181032e+07
#2   7.890700e+04
#3  -1.881100e-01
#4  -2.173739e-01
#5   1.004335e+01
#6  -1.395662e-03
#7  -1.953578e-03
#8   8.369365e-02
#9  -1.266804e+00
#10 -1.850343e+00
#11  2.000000e+00
```

#### data

```
v1 <- "[ 1.18103230e+07 7.89070000e+04 -1.88109969e-01 -2.17373938e-01\n 1.00433488e+01 -1.39566174e-03 -1.95357823e-03 8.36936470e-02\n -1.26680427e+00 -1.85034338e+00 2.00000000e+00]"
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun ! fread works well, however I seem to get a 3x4 (with a NA value), dataframe instead of a 1x11 dataframe (which I wanted). I tried to flatten it, but then the order of the columns changes. Any way around this?

Comment: @beetzfan  Sure, it is because of `\n` in your data.  We can change it by removing the `\n` or do an `unlist` later